# Remove unused css / js code on Release Build in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio, minify

Is there a way to remove unused CSS / JS from the Release Build files? Similar to how you can minify files on Release Build.

Basically, when I build my Release code, I'd like to have unused CSS / JS removed, but only in the built files. I'd like it still available in my project in case I do want to use it later on. I'd like to clean up things like extra crap from bootstrap.css and such.

Comment: This looks like a job for you. Why would you leave unused code in your JS / CSS  ?  There is linting tools that can help you figure out which code is unused, but you still have to do it yourself.

Comment: Detecting unused JS code isn't foolproof, either.  If I had code like `obj[a+b]`, can you tell me if `obj.memberFirst` is unused, when it depends on the values `a` and `b` take at runtime?

Comment: @Nicolas For cleaning up unused code from libraries, mainly. Of course, most of my code is being used, but not everything from a library... which is a lot. I don't want to strip out 75% of a library like bootstrap in case I want to use some of its functionality in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use Webpack's [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

Module bundler's like Webpack do it on the fly with the cost of minor configuration effort.

Answer (score 0):

One soulution would be to comment the unused css out and remove all comments from the build.

You could use optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin to remove comments,
Example : https://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/webpack-remove-comments-compressed-css